# Qiskit in Colab

Tags: quantum-computing, qiskit

I'm running a simple script in Google Colab, but it gives an error in the line: `job = execute(circ, backend, shots=1)`

```
 TranspilerError: 'Invalid plugin name sabre for stage routing'
```

Could someone point the issue with the code?

Here is the code:

```
#Install Qiskit in the Colab environment
!pip install qiskit qiskit-ibmq-provider qiskit-aer

# Correctly import necessary modules
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.providers.ibmq import IBMQ  
from qiskit.providers.ibmq import least_busy
from qiskit_aer import Aer
from qiskit.execute_function import execute  

IBMQ.save_account('API_TOKEN', overwrite=True)

IBMQ.load_account()

backend = IBMQ.get_provider().get_backend('ibmq_qasm_simulator')
# Create one qubit
circ = QuantumCircuit(1, 1)
# Put the qubit in superposition (0 and 1 at the same time)
circ.h(0)
# Measure the qubit
circ.measure(0, 0)
# Run the circuit on the local simulator
job = execute(circ, backend, shots=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `qiskit.execute_function` was removed in qiskit-1.0 (see [releasenote](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit/blob/main/releasenotes/notes/remove-execute-699e9aca1662c174.yaml)).

Instead of using the `execute` function, just run the following

```
# transpile to backend
circ_ = transpile(circ, backend=backend)
job = backend.run(circ_)
result = job.result()
counts = result.get_counts()
counts
```