# i am not able to import execute from qiskit

Tags: python, command, qiskit

so the problem I am facing is when I run this command
from qiskit import execute
I am getting this error
cannot import execute from qiskit
I have tried asking every known source for the solution but no use so can anyone help me with this issue

Comment: The execute module was removed from qiskit in version 1.0, check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78069676/qiskit-in-colab/78073641#78073641

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `execute` works in Qiskit 0.* and it was removed in Qiskit 1.*. See the migration guide [here](https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/migration-guides/qiskit-1.0-features#execute).